# how can i turn to GPU

Tags: pytorch, gpu, image-classification

how can i turn this classifier to run n the GPU
i tryed to add resent18.cuda() but it gave me an error in when I run the train(epochs=20) and when i run show_preds() before train(epochs=20) and the error that desplays it :
**RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same**
can you help me to do it

```
import os
import shutil
import random
import torch
import torchvision
import numpy as np
from google.colab import files
import time 
import copy 
import urllib
import torch
import PIL
import json
import numpy as np
import torch.nn.functional as F
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

torch.manual_seed(0)
class_names = ['normal', 'viral', 'covid']
root_dir = 'COVID-19 Radiography Database'
source_dirs = ['NORMAL', 'Viral Pneumonia', 'COVID-19']

if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root_dir, source_dirs[1])):
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_dir, 'test'))

    for i, d in enumerate(source_dirs):
        os.rename(os.path.join(root_dir, d), os.path.join(root_dir, class_names[i]))

    for c in class_names:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_dir, 'test', c))

    for c in class_names:
        images = [x for x in os.listdir(os.path.join(root_dir, c)) if x.lower().endswith('png')]
        selected_images = random.sample(images, 30)
        for image in selected_images:
            source_path = os.path.join(root_dir, c, image)
            target_path = os.path.join(root_dir, 'test', c, image)
            shutil.move(source_path, target_path)
class ChestXRayDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, image_dirs, transform):
        def get_images(class_name):
            images = [x for x in os.listdir(image_dirs[class_name]) if x[-3:].lower().endswith('png')]
            print(f'Found {len(images)} {class_name} examples')
            return images
        
        self.images = {}
        self.class_names = ['normal', 'viral', 'covid']
        
        for class_name in self.class_names:
            self.images[class_name] = get_images(class_name)
            
        self.image_dirs = image_dirs
        self.transform = transform
        
    
    def __len__(self):
        return sum([len(self.images[class_name]) for class_name in self.class_names])
    
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        class_name = random.choice(self.class_names)
        index = index % len(self.images[class_name])
        image_name = self.images[class_name][index]
        image_path = os.path.join(self.image_dirs[class_name], image_name)
        image = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')
        return self.transform(image), self.class_names.index(class_name)
train_transform = torchvision.transforms.Compose([
    torchvision.transforms.Resize(size=(224, 224)),
    torchvision.transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
    torchvision.transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])

test_transform = torchvision.transforms.Compose([
    torchvision.transforms.Resize(size=(224, 224)),
    torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
    torchvision.transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])
train_dirs = {
    'normal': '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/covidcalssifierdataset/COVID-19 Radiography Database/normal',
    'viral': '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/covidcalssifierdataset/COVID-19 Radiography Database/viral',
    'covid': '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/covidcalssifierdataset/COVID-19 Radiography Database/covid'
}

train_dataset = ChestXRayDataset(train_dirs, train_transform)

test_dirs = {
    'normal': '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/covidcalssifierdataset/COVID-19 Radiography Database/test/normal',
    'viral': '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/covidcalssifierdataset/COVID-19 Radiography Database/test/normal',
    'covid': '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/covidcalssifierdataset/COVID-19 Radiography Database/test/covid'
}

test_dataset = ChestXRayDataset(test_dirs, test_transform)
batch_size = 6

dl_train = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
dl_test = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

print('Number of training batches', len(dl_train))
print('Number of test batches', len(dl_test))
class_names = train_dataset.class_names


def show_images(images, labels, preds):
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
    for i, image in enumerate(images):
        plt.subplot(1, 6, i + 1, xticks=[], yticks=[])
        image = image.numpy().transpose((1, 2, 0))
        mean = np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
        std = np.array([0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
        image = image * std + mean
        image = np.clip(image, 0., 1.)
        plt.imshow(image)
        col = 'green'
        if preds[i] != labels[i]:
            col = 'red'
            
        plt.xlabel(f'{class_names[int(labels[i].numpy())]}')
        plt.ylabel(f'{class_names[int(preds[i].numpy())]}', color=col)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
images, labels = next(iter(dl_train))
show_images(images, labels, labels)
images, labels = next(iter(dl_test))
show_images(images, labels, labels)
resnet18 = torchvision.models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
resnet18.fc = torch.nn.Linear(in_features=512, out_features=3)
loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(resnet18.parameters(), lr=3e-5)
def show_preds():
    resnet18.eval()
    images, labels = next(iter(dl_test))
    outputs = resnet18(images)
    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
    show_images(images, labels, press)
def train(epochs):
    print('Starting training..')
    for e in range(0, epochs):
        print('='*20)
        print(f'Starting epoch {e + 1}/{epochs}')
        print('='*20)

        train_loss = 0.
        val_loss = 0.

        resnet18.train() # set model to training phase

        for train_step, (images, labels) in enumerate(dl_train):
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = resnet18(images)
            loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            train_loss += loss.item()
            if train_step % 20 == 0:
                print('Evaluating at step', train_step)

                accuracy = 0

                resnet18.eval() # set model to eval phase

                for val_step, (images, labels) in enumerate(dl_test):
                    outputs = resnet18(images)
                    loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)
                    val_loss += loss.item()

                    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                    accuracy += sum((preds == labels).numpy())

                val_loss /= (val_step + 1)
                accuracy = accuracy/len(test_dataset)
                print(f'Validation Loss: {val_loss:.4f}, Accuracy: {accuracy:.4f}')

                show_preds()

                resnet18.train()

                if accuracy >= 0.95:
                    print('Performance condition satisfied, stopping..')
                    return

        train_loss /= (train_step + 1)

        print(f'Training Loss: {train_loss:.4f}')
    print('Training complete..')


train(epochs=20)
```

Comment: To fix your error, you need to move the inputs to the GPU as well: `images.cuda()`. Your code has other issues, but to run it on GPU, moving the model and inputs to the GPU will do it.

Comment: were i willl but the images.cuda() in my code 
and could you tell me what are the other issues